# how to run process in background in .net using c#

Tags: c#, .net, process, background

I have to run process in background using thread and background worker. this process do the task of retrieve data from database,it retrieve successfully by I can not display that data into datagridview, there is give some data error event.

Comment: what exception message are you getting?

Comment: @haresh chande: first thing you should do is search SO and elesewhere and compare the examples of how to use the backgroundworker class...

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: to update the ui, you need to be on the main thread. This is the case in most all languages. This prevents the UI from being "stepped on" by background threads.. Add a method to the container of the datagridview that will take the background data and update the UI and invoke that on the object's method in the main ui thread, thereby aggregating your data to the easiest traversable result in the background, and having the least amount of time on the UI thread possible.

Answer (score 3):

BackgroundWorker has a built in callback method of `RunWorkerCompleted` that you wire into and it handles the cross thread marshaling to the UI thread automatically. Before you call `RunWorkerAsync` you can wire into the the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += 
                new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

within the `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` you can bind your grid or set the DataSource property to the DataTable and it will be on the UI thread.

If you have already done this and are getting errors it might just be an unhandled exception within the DoWork/threaded code itself. If that is the case wrap the `RunWorkerAsync` call in a try catch and see what you get.

Hope that help...

Answer (score -2):

May be you are unable to modify the DataGridView Control.
Set 
CheckForCrossThreadcalls = false
,it may works

Comment: That's not good advice. That setting is there to alert the developer that they're doing something wrong. What you recommend is basically the same as telling someone if their smoke detector goes off just take out the batteries and go back to sleep.